# How to use first image in a post as my excerpt thumbnail, not my set featured image

Tags: php, image, wordpress

I currently have featured images set on my child Twenty Twelve theme. I use the featured image as a dynamic header to go at the top of the page when on a post.
However, the featured images I use have text over them so look weird and cut off when put into the excerpt thumbnail in a square format.

Is there a way I can still keep my featured images set, but pull the first content post image and display it as a thumbnail in my excerpts? I have found how to pull the first image across but it displays as a full size image. I really want it to automatically be a 'thumbnail' in terms of dimension and cropping.

Essentially I want to use the 'Easy Add Thumbnail' plugin but this does not work if I already have  featured image set...

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a specific image size in your functions.php file using add_image_size(); (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size);

Essentially you just add this to your functions file....

```
add_image_size( 'seattle-sized', 420, 420, true );
```

Then, when calling that first image, you can apply 'seattle-sized' to the image like this...

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 42, 'seattle-sized' ) ?>
```

The trick is that true at the end of add_image_size, it tells it to crop that bad boy.

Hope this helps!